# Downloading videos and photos into Photos when my app is downloaded

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I am developing a presentation app with Swift. For user tutorial, I want to add some photos and videos to the app. Then when the app is downloaded, the photos and videos are downloaded into Photos on devices so that users can use the videos and photos for the tutorial. Is it possible? or is there any way to make it possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save an image to camera roll you can use:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageToBeSaved, nil, nil, nil)
```

Just run this when the users start the tutorial!

If you don't know how to add photo's to your app: Simply go to your Assets.xcassets folder and right click the '+' button and add an Image Set!

Comment: That works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: No problem! You can accept the answer by clicking the check box

Comment: I did~ Thanks again~!